# how to keep uv maps of duplicated objects stacked on each other when averaging and packing?

Tags: stack, blender

I have an object with similar parts, I unwrap uv of one, and then transfer to the other similar ones. When I finally join all of parts of the assembly to combine to a single map, I do average islands scales (ctrl+A) and pack islands (ctrl+P) with hot keys for windows. This final hot key operation breaks my efforts to keep similar islands stacked and I found no solution for this by googling (perhaps just wrong keywords the reason).

How to let Blender to know to lock my stacks when averaging / packing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pin uvs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/layout.html#pin-and-unpin) so they don't move when you unwrap.

You should be ok pinning two or four verts in an island but [selecting linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/selecting.html) <kbd>L</kbd> and pinning <kbd>P</kbd> all of them is usually easier.

There is a [blender SE site](https://blender.stackexchange.com) which is better for questions about using blender.